# Flutter - How I make date format day on/off unlimited

Tags: flutter, date

Flutter - How I make date format day on/off auto unlimited

```css
List<DateTime> onDates = [
  DateTime(2021, 03, 1),
  DateTime(2021, 03, 3),
];
List<DateTime> offDates = [
  DateTime(2021, 03, 2),
  DateTime(2021, 03, 4),
];
```

[image: Flutter - How I make date format day on/off auto unlimited]

Comment: Can you be more explicit please ? Share more information about your problem and image, and some code if needed.

Comment: I added short code